# how does copy work in windows?

Tags: windows

I want to find out about the process that is triggered when the copy command of the Windows OS is called. I want to know about how the memory is used and if it is used and so on.

Can anyone point me with some eferences? Maybe a book in which the process is described? 
I want to learn the process in order to optimize the loading process of some files into the memory.

Comment: In my experience it almost never pays to try to second guess O/S design in this way. I generally assume that people that work on critical parts of mature operating systems are amongst the most intelligent, have many years of experience and deep knowledge. They assume most of the end-users use the O/S in the obvious ways and so optimise the O/S for that. Therefore I will get best performance by using my O/S in the most obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up Process monitor to any process and get a list of all the System calls it makes.

What kind of files are you looking to load up.